# Semaphore not incresing or decresing

Tags: c#, synchronization, semaphore

I am just finish learning semaphore and sychronization, and doing a producer-consumer experiment, and here's the code in C#

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MutexExperiment {
    class Program { 
        static int MaxCount => 10;
        private static Mutex Mutex = new Mutex();

        // number of empty buffer
        static SemaphoreSlim Empty => new(MaxCount, MaxCount);
        static SemaphoreSlim Full => new(0, MaxCount);
        static Queue<int> Buffer => new();

        public static void Producer() {
            while (true) {
                var pro = new Random().Next(0, 100);
                Empty.Wait();
                Console.WriteLine($"Empty: {Empty.CurrentCount}");
                
                Mutex.WaitOne();
                Buffer.Enqueue(pro);
                Mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                
                Full.Release();
                Console.WriteLine($"Full: {Full.CurrentCount}");
                Console.WriteLine($"New production:\t{pro}");
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        public static void Consumer() {
            while (true) {
                Full.Wait();
                
                Mutex.WaitOne();
                var item = Buffer.Dequeue();
                Mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                
                Empty.Release();
                Console.WriteLine($"Consumed:\t{item}");
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        public static void Main() {
            var producer = new Thread(Producer);
            var consumer = new Thread(Consumer);
            
            consumer.Start();
            producer.Start();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I have noticing that every time the `Empty` and `Full` will always be `10` and `0`, though I have performed `Wait` and `Release` on it.
Output:

```
Empty: 10
Full: 0
New production: 67
Empty: 10
Full: 0
New production: 64
```

Is something I did wrong?

Comment: What did you expect? Certainly, the code is working as it should. You only have one thread waiting on each semaphore, and the threads are coordinating with each other, so when they are each released from their wait, each semaphore will of course be back to its original state. Presumably the above is just an academic exercise. You should use `BlockingCollection<T>` for simple producer/consumer scenarios (and for more complex ones, consider the Data Workflow API).

Answer (score 0):

Wrongly put semaphores as a field with only a getter.
Just change them to property, and it will work properly.

```cs
static SemaphoreSlim Empty = new(MaxCount, MaxCount);
static SemaphoreSlim Full = new(0, MaxCount);
static Queue<int> Buffer = new();
```